# How can I assign a string to an IntelHex value?

Tags: python, hex, bin

I have a problem with automatically changing the value in the intehex object.
If I were to do the manual operation everything is fine, but when I want to use str or hex it doesn't work properly. Example:

```
text = "0xff"

ih[i] = 0xff # OK
ih[i] = text # Invalid change
```

Part of my code:

```
from intelhex import IntelHex
ih = IntelHex()
ih.loadbin('golf.bin')
driver_injection = "34 0D 84 0D E8 0D 10 0E 42 0E"
driver_inj_list = driver_injection.split()

element = "0x"
count = 0

for i in range(379436,379711):
    changer = element + driver_inj_list[count]
    ih[i] = changer

    count += 1
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: Try `int(text, base=16)`.

Comment: Works as it should. Thank you.